# How to create 'up-down' bars in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, dundas

In Excel, you can create up-down bars, where the bar appears 'above' or 'below' some other value, with +ve and -ve being different colours

see here for an example: http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/StockChartsAndLineChartTricks.html

Is it possible to do this in SSRS, the closest I've seen is candlestick charts

I can use Dundas Chart for Reporting Services if that's any use

Comment: Looking at the link you provided, I don't see any that have two bars of different colors in the same column. Which chart are you trying to recreate? you can impose multiple charts on top of each other, in case you are trying to get the colored lines on top of the candlestick charts.

Comment: An 'up down' chart is one where values appear above or below an imaginary X-axis (parallel to and above the normal x-axis). Values above this axis are one colour, below are another colour

Answer (score 0):

[I really misunderstood your question, so I'm massively rewriting this answer.]

The functionality you describe is part of the standard stacked bar chart if you want the values stacked or the standard bar chart if you don't want values stacked.

I created a query of

```
Select
'Eastern' AS Region,
450 AS UpValue,
-30 AS DownValue

Union ALL
Select
'Middle',
300,
0
UNION ALL
Select
'Western',
400,
-100
```

Then added a Stacked bar chart and dragged the UpValue and DownValue to Values, and Region to Category.

My results:
[image]

Comment: I'm not using R2, as stated in the tags. Good to know though

Comment: The solution I'm working with was migrated from 2005, complete with Dundas. I'll see if using the 'built in' charts is an option, there are tons of legacy charts using Dundas so they may not wish to go down that particular route

Comment: Edited to provide a better answer.